# How to count number of leaf nodes in a binary tree using queue?

Tags: c

I am learning c language. It's Preety  simple to count the leaf nodes in a binary treee using recursion but how can we do it using a queue ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'leaf nodes'? What are you trying to do? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Leaf nodes as in a binary tree .

Comment: Please update the question with your code.

Comment: Use a `while` loop to follow the left node, placing any right node in the queue. When you reach a leaf, resume with a node from the queue, until the queue is empty.

Comment: How leaf that are in the subtree of left node will be counted?

Comment: If you follow the left node, there is one and only one leaf.

Comment: Can u please write a algo or code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Do a breadth first traversal of the tree using a queue and check if a particular node has both the children `NULL`.

Pseudocode:

```
queue = [root]
count = 0
while !queue.empty():
    current_node = queue.dequeue()
    if (current_node.left == NULL) and (current_node.right == NULL):
        count += 1
        continue
    if (current_node.left != NULL):
        queue.enqueue(current_node.left)
    if (current_node.right != NULL):
        queue.enqueue(current_node.right)

print count
```

Comment: I dont know if I am wrong but I think it is still using recursion

Comment: No, it doesn't. Where exactly do you see recursion?

Comment: No, `queue.enqueue` is just like adding an element at the end of the array. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722216/implementing-a-simple-queue-using-arrays#8722306

Comment: Ok yeah I understand its not. But if the right node is not null we enqueue it in a queue and after that what is going to happen?

Comment: Understand how breadth first search works. Everything will be clear then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687731/breadth-first-vs-depth-first

Comment: It is a kind of a traversal. You traverse the tree layer by layer top to bottom.